# Disposing a form from parent form in C#?

Tags: c#, class, forms, object, dispose

I have a form which will open a new form when one button (form1button) is clicked. And on the child form there will be another button 'form2button'. Now if I click this form2button the new form2 should be disposed. But because the form2 object is created here in form1 class method, I cannot dispose that object in form2 class method (fom2buttonclick). So I used static to get my work done as in the following psuedo code.

Form1:

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    static Form2 f2;

    public void Form1_buttonclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f2 = new Form2();
    }

    public void Disposef2()
    {
        f2.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Form2:

```
class Form2 : Form
{
    public void Form2_buttonclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        f1.Disposef2();
    }
}
```

Is there any other better way to do it. Or C# design itself doesnot provide an alternative mechanism. I am new to C#.Please help me out..

**Edit**

I want to close (dispose explicitely) form2 object which is created in form1 class when button on form2 is clicked. This edit is to give some more clarity.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are trying to do? If you only ever want one instance of the second form, then using the static is fine.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to Dispose form2 at all, could you clarify the "Why" behind it so we can help you better?

Comment: I am showing a picture on form2 when button on form1 is clicked and I am disposing that form2 when a button on form2 is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the two forms doesn't have a parent-dialog type of relationship, you might just want to hook into the Disposed event on the subform to get notified when it closes.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 _Form2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_Form2 != null)
            _Form2.Dispose();

        _Form2 = new Form2();
        _Form2.Disposed += delegate
        {
            _Form2.Dispose();
            _Form2 = null;
        };
        _Form2.Show();
    }
}
```

Then all you have to do in Form2 is simply to close it:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you call _Form2.Dispose() inside of the delegate, if it's already disposing?

Answer (score 7):

MSDN docs on disposing of forms:

> Dispose will be called automatically
>   if the form is shown using the Show
>   method. If another method such as
>   ShowDialog is used, or the form is
>   never shown at all, you must call
>   Dispose yourself within your
>   application.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aw58wzka.aspx)

On closing vs. disposing:

> When a form is closed, all resources
>   created within the object are closed
>   and the form is disposed. You can
>   prevent the closing of a form at run
>   time by handling the Closing event and
>   setting the Cancel property of the
>   CancelEventArgs passed as a parameter
>   to your event handler. If the form you
>   are closing is the startup form of
>   your application, your application
>   ends.
>
> The two conditions when a form is not
>   disposed on Close is when (1) it is
>   part of a multiple-document interface
>   (MDI) application, and the form is not
>   visible; and (2) you have displayed
>   the form using ShowDialog. In these
>   cases, you will need to call Dispose
>   manually to mark all of the form's
>   controls for garbage collection.

Comment: It seems like if you call Close() "when it is part of a multiple-document interface (MDI) application, and the form is not visible" it is disposed anyway. At least it is in my tests.

Comment: The second part of the answer is based on an old version of the framework. Anyone interested in the updated version of the Closing Event should look here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to explicitly call Dispose on the form, the garbage collector will do that for you.
2. If you want something specific to happen when Form2 "goes away", you can hook into it's form closing event.

**EDIT :**

On Form2, in the button click, try

```
this->Close();
```

That will close that instance of form2 (the form will disappear). If form1 still has a reference to form2, then form2 will not be picked up by the garbage collector, and the GC will not dispose of it.

If there is a reason for form1 to keep a reference to form2 ?

If so, form1 should handle from2's closing event, then form1 can release it's reference to form2 (set it to null).

Now the GC will pickup form2 as a candidate to be collected, it will (in possibly more than one step) call it's Dispose method and free up Form2's memory.

Comment: ya, but I want to dispose second form when button2 on form2 is clicked. how to do it?

Comment: If you hook into its close event, that creates an event handler you'll have to remove as well correct?  *sigh* memory leaks are such a pain.

Answer (score 1):

You are not really a reader right? Lot of answers here already.

> Edit I want to close(dispose
>   explicitely) form2 object which is
>   created in form1 class when button on
>   form2 is clicked. This edit is to give
>   some more clarity.

If you use ShowDialog then form2 returns when you call close(). So in Form1:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 oForm2 = new Form2();
    oForm2.MyParentForm = this;
    if (oForm2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        oForm2.Dispose(); //or oForm2.Close() what you want
    }
}
```

And then call Close() in form2.

Answer (score 0):

I did this once for my project, to close one application and open another application.

```
    System.Threading.Thread newThread;
    Form1 frmNewForm = new Form1;

   newThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(frmNewFormThread));
this.Close();
        newThread.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
        newThread.Start();
```

And add the following Method. Your newThread.Start will call this method.

```
    public void frmNewFormThread)()
    {

        Application.Run(frmNewForm);

    }
```